# Pandas, groupby by 2 non numeric columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with several columns that I only need to use 2 non numeric columns

1 is 'hashed_id' another is 'event name' with 10 unique names
I'm trying to do a groupby by 2 non numeric columns, so aggregation functions would not work here

my solution is:

```
df_events = df.groupby('subscription_hash', 'event_name')['event_name']
df_events = pd.DataFrame (df_events, columns = ["subscription_hash", 
'event_name'])
```

I'm trying to get a format like:

```
subscription_hash                                          event_name
                         
0   (0000379144f24717a8d124d798008a0e672)                       AddToQueue
1   (0000379144f24717a8d124d798008a0e672)                       page_view
```

but instead getting:

```
  subscription_hash                                             event_name  

0   (0000379144f24717a8d124d798008a0e672)                       832433 AddToQueue 
1   (0000379144f24717a8d124d798008a0e672)                       245400 page_view
```

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Is your data clean ? what are those undesired numbers coming from ?

from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), I see groupby being used by providing the name of columns as a list and an aggregate function:

`df.groupby(['col1','col2']).mean()`

since your values are not numeric maybe try the [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) method:

`df.pivot(columns=['col1','col2'])`

so id try first putting [] around your colnames, then try the pivot.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is clean, no idea where it is coming from.

Was thinking I have made some mistake in groupby code.

Do you think it is correct?

Comment: df_events = df.pivot(columns=['subscription_hash','event_name'])


getting this error:


    ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected 1791873 rows, received array of length 2

Comment: Hey do you mind sharing what your df looks like ? 
```df.head()```

if all you want is to have those 2 columns and no aggregates then,
```df_events = df[['col1','cols']]```